# Jenkins takes a comma from the version information fields

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins (TRM) sets in the setup config (the firmware section) a comma instead of the relative location of the directory, even though "using configuration" in the console shows the correct location. the comma appears in the JK build parameters, seems JK overwrites the key from the config.json

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this comma charecter, go to Advanced: [Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEAl2.png)

And enable : [Omit value field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tta1r.png)